# Update on non-standardized hierarchy data

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I have a table with three columns: Parent, Child and Flag. When a Child has its own Children, it appers also in the Parent column.

The hierarchy has no standardized level, so, a member can have level six as the last whilst other member can have its last level at 3.

Example:

```
1
- 1.1
-- 1.1.1
--- 1.1.1.1
- 1.2
-- 1.2.1
- 1.3
-- 1.3.1
--- 1.3.1.1
----1.3.1.1.1
2
- 2.1
-- 2.1.1
...
```

What I need is to update the Flag of the records which Parent starts with 1, and its children, and children of children, and so on... in this case, only:

```
1
- 1.1
-- 1.1.1
--- 1.1.1.1
- 1.2
-- 1.2.1
- 1.3
-- 1.3.1
--- 1.3.1.1
----1.3.1.1.1
```

But remember that in the table it is not structured like that, but in two columns, like:

```
Parent    |Child
1          1.1
1          1.2
1          1.3
1.1        1.1.1
1.1.1      1.1.1.1
1.2        1.2.1
...
```

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: where `child like input_parent_id||'.%'` won't help you?

Comment: No, because the hierarchy is not organized like this (this was just an example). Actually data are more like: (L1) CT-100000 -> (L2) CT-101022 -> (L3) CT- 980009 ...

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you'r question you want to update rows by their first parent. 
you can do that with `connect_by_root` look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#i2053935).

basically (haven't tested it) something like that

```
update  hierarchy_table h_outer
set     flag = 'X'
where   h_outer.rowid in (
    select rid 
    from    (
        select  h.row_id as rid , connect_by_root parent_id as root_parent
        from    hierarchy_table h
        start with parent = null 
        connect by prior child_id = parent_id
        ) 
    where root_parent like '1%'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this fulfills your requirement

```
UPDATE hierarchy_table a
   SET a.flag = 'X'
 WHERE a.ROWID IN (SELECT b.ROWID
                     FROM hierarchy_table b
                    START WITH b.PARENT = '1' -- Change start point here
                  CONNECT BY PRIOR b.child = b.PARENT);
```

Comment: I think it is generating a cartesian. Heard of something called NOCYCLE... Maybe this can help... I am setting the start point, but even thought the query never ends...

Comment: Just to let you know, the hierarchy is not organized like 1, 1.1 ... (this was just an example). Actually data are more like: (L1) CT-100000 -> (L2) CT-101022 -> (L3) CT- 980009 ...

Comment: It doesn't matter what the data is unless there is parent - child relationship. This query worked perfectly for me in Oracle 11.0.0.1.0. Moreover, its explain plan is not showing any Cartesian. But that's a good point anyways, better to provide alias. NOCYCLE is required if at some point of time a parent has a child that was a prior parent and your example doesn't demonstrated that.